# 15 amp receptacles on 20 amp circuit

Tags: wiring

While doing other projects I discovered that my receptacles (garage ceiling) are 15 amp rated but are on 20 amp circuit. House is 20+ years old.

What does it mean?

1. 20-year old code allowed this?
2. Special case for garage ceiling receptacles?
3. House was not built according to the code?
4. Somebody did the work not according to the code afterwards (previous owner)?

Also - these receptacles are not GFCI protected. Inspector did mention another not protected receptacle (at the time code didn't require it) but didn't mention that these receptacles need to be protected. Does it mean there is something special in this case?

Comment: These are *duplex* receptacles, (two receptacles on one yoke), right?

Comment: Yes. Marked the question as duplicate